# Numpy: regrid by averaging?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to regrid a numpy array onto a new grid.  In this specific case, I'm trying to regrid a power spectrum onto a logarithmic grid so that the data are evenly spaced logarithmically for plotting purposes.

Doing this with straight interpolation using `np.interp` results in some of the original data being ignored entirely.  Using `digitize` gets the result I want, but I have to use some ugly loops to get it to work:

```
xfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(100)[1:50] # only positive, nonzero freqs
psw = np.arange(xfreq.size) # dummy array for MWE

# new logarithmic grid
logfreq = np.logspace(np.log10(np.min(xfreq)), np.log10(np.max(xfreq)), 100)

inds = np.digitize(xfreq,logfreq)

# interpolation: ignores data *but* populates all points
logpsw  = np.interp(logfreq, xfreq, psw)
# so average down where available...
logpsw[np.unique(inds)] = [psw[inds==i].mean() for i in np.unique(inds)]

# the new plot
loglog(logfreq, logpsw, linewidth=0.5, color='k')
```

Is there a nicer way to accomplish this in numpy?  I'd be satisfied with just a replacement of the inline loop step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bincount()` twice to calculate the average value of every bins:

```
logpsw2  = np.interp(logfreq, xfreq, psw)
counts = np.bincount(inds)
mask = counts != 0
logpsw2[mask] = np.bincount(inds, psw)[mask] / counts[mask]
```

or use `unique(inds, return_inverse=True)` and `bincount()` twice:

```
logpsw4  = np.interp(logfreq, xfreq, psw)
uinds, inv_index = np.unique(inds, return_inverse=True)
logpsw4[uinds] = np.bincount(inv_index, psw) / np.bincount(inv_index)
```

Or if you use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
logpsw4  = np.interp(logfreq, xfreq, psw)
s = pd.groupby(pd.Series(psw), inds).mean()
logpsw4[s.index] = s.values
```

Comment: Cool.  `pandas` would be a bit heavy for just this use, so I like the `bincount` approach.  I don't think this solution can be used for medians, though - can you think up a way to do it for medians/percentiles?